# Как отключить подсветку выделенного элемента в ListBox с динамическим шаблоном для ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача была написать ListBox с элементами в виде обычного TextBlock и Expander с табличкой. Ну и я решил ещё потренироваться с выделением. Хотел сделать выделение рамкой. 
Написал переключатель шаблонов

```
internal sealed class ListBoxDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{        
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var control = container as FrameworkElement;
        var element = item as ProfileWrapper; 
        if (element == null || control == null)
            return null;

        if (element.AssignedProfiles == null || element.AssignedProfiles.Count == 0)
        {
            return control.FindResource("DefaultItemTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else if (element.AssignedProfiles != null && element.AssignedProfiles.Count > 0)
        {
            return control.FindResource("ItemTemplateWithExpander") as DataTemplate;                
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Вот разметка xaml. Я Expander опустил так как там кода много, а вопрос его не касается.

```
<cg:PageControl x:Class="AFP_GUI.SecurityProfileSync.SPSync"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AFP_GUI.SecurityProfileSync"
         xmlns:cg="clr-namespace:CommonGUI;assembly=CommonGUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" 
         d:DesignWidth="700">
<Control.Resources>
    <local:SPSyncViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate" DataType="ListBoxItem">

        <Border x:Name="xxx"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Green">
            <TextBlock x:Name="yyy" Text="{Binding ProfileName}">
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  IsSelected, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                           AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem} } }" 
                         Value="True">                    
                <Setter TargetName="xxx" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                <Setter TargetName="xxx" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>                          
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ListBoxDataTemplateSelector x:Key="dataTemplateSelector"/>

</Control.Resources>

<ListBox Margin="5" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding QPProfileList}" 
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}"
                         >
                </ListBox>
```

Так вот выделение рамкой то есть, да вот проблема есть ещё и стандартная заливка выделенного элемента. А вот как её убрать, что-то я не догадался... Может кто подскажет. Буду благодарен

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему следующим способом. Переопределил для ListBox ControlTemplate

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">                                           
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```